# Wrapping annotation along with text

Tags: html, css

I have a thing where I'm annotating certain words in a paragraph with a label of sorts.

I have a label scheme that works as I want it to, except when the annotated text wraps, the label runs off the side. I'd like the label to either go to the next line or wrap with the text itself.

Here's what I have: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YmwmbL

```
<div class="container">

You can label <span class="word-group"><span class="label">big long label that spans multiple words</span></span> <em>highlighted text that wraps to two lines</em>. I want "spans multiple words" to wrap so that it appears under "that wraps to two lines." Failing that, I want the whole label to jump to the next line.</p>

</div>

.container {
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 30px
}

em label {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -16px;
    height: 22px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px;
    z-index: -1;
    line-height: 19px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 200%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -50%;
    color: #004e95;
}

.word-group {
    position: relative;
}

.label {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -23px;
    height: 21px;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
    z-index: -1;
    line-height: 13px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    color: #004e95;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I can only use HTML and CSS with this. The solution doesn't have to use my existing framework, that's just where I'm starting from.

Here's an artist's rendering of what I'm looking for: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ke5b2ho1sdidm2h/wrap.png?dl=0

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KOzPoN

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! Actually, I want the label to be under the text it is annotating rather than inline with it.

Comment: Just realized I hadn't saved my codepen, so hopefully it should be clearer now.

Comment: Like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KOzPoN ?

Comment: But I'm confused. You want to break the line only if the span is too long to finish the line or even if it's short?

Comment: Here's an image of what I want if that clears things up: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ke5b2ho1sdidm2h/wrap.png?dl=0